# How to open a file with vim without showing number and relativenumber

Tags: vim

I have options set in `~/.vimrc` that always show number and relativenumber. But sometimes I know prior to opening the file that I don't want such options, so I'm seeking a way to disable such options only when I open such file without a need to modify `~/.vimrc` again, then again to turn them back on, or even additional step to set it after successfully opened a file via `:set nonumber` and `:set norelativenumber`.

Something along the line of `vim +100 input.txt` to jump straight to line 100 when open `input.txt` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Something along the line of vim +100 input.txt to jump straight to line 100 when open input.txt file.

Sure, you could use `vim +'set nonu|set nornu' input.txt` and even create an alias such as

```
alias vimnonu="vim +'set nonu|set nornu'"
```

You could also create mappings in your `.vimrc` to activate/deactivate both options at once such as

```
nnoremap <leader>nonu :set nonu\|set nornu<CR>
nnoremap <leader>num :set nu\|set rnu<CR>
```

but I would strongly recommand you look at topoe's [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin which provides plenty of bracket-based mappings to change usefull options on the fly.

Quote from `:h unimpaired`

> ```
> On      Off     Toggle  Option
> [on     ]on     yon     'number'
> [or     ]or     yor     'relativenumber'
> ```